# Google Charts: how to preserve zoom when changing data

Tags: google-visualization

I am drawing an area chart, and providing the user with some extra controls, beside the chart, to change the value of the currently selected point.
I am also using the **explorer** option to provide zoom and pan.

I am facing two problems with zoom:

1) The mouse wheel effect is reversed, compared to google maps: wheel-down means zoom-in! Is there any option to reverse the wheel effect?

2) When the user changes the value of the selected point, I redraw the chart in order to show the change, but this causes the zoom to reset. Is there any way to change chart values without redrawing, or to preserve zoom across redraw?

Comment: The solution to problem 1 is to set zoomDelta to less than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given up the built-in zoom feature, and choosen to handle it in a different way.

The chart, or to better say, the "overlay" containing the chart and the markers, is put inside a div having a style like this:

```
.myChartBox {
    border: 1px solid #2080c0;
    width: 900px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

I havo no longer the chart **explorer** option, and I am handling the **wheel** event like this:

```
var currentZoom = 1;

function handleWheel(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.deltaY < 0 && currentZoom < 8)
        currentZoom *= 2;
    else if (event.deltaY > 0 && currentZoom > 1)
        currentZoom /= 2;
    myChartOptions.width = 900 * currentZoom;
    myChart.draw(myChartData, myChartOptions);
}
```

The user can now zoom in or out by using the mouse wheel the same way as in google maps, and scroll left or right the chart using the horizontal scrollbar (pan implementation wouldn't be difficult, either). And I can redraw the chart any time I change the data, without loosing the zoom level.

I still hope some better solution is suggested.